# Trouble redirecting from javascript

Tags: jquery, redirect, navigation

I have page1.aspx and page2.aspx in a website

I need to navigate as: Page1--> Page 2(on click of go back button, back to page1)--> page 1

I am using jQuery code to navigate:

```
   var pagename= "page2.aspx";
   jQ(location).attr('href', pagename);
```

I tried using same code in page2 to navigate back to page 1:

```
var path2 = "page1.aspx";
        jq(location).attr('href', path2);
```

also tried below code and similar few others as well.

```
document.location.pathname = '../Pages/page1.aspx';
```

But all it does is, navigate me to Directory Listing, where it shows all page names under pages folder. Is there anything wrong with the code ? I tried to do it as per levels too, that is  ../pages/page1.aspx .

Updated:

I am using following control on click of which I am calling the code:

```
  <a href="" class="hyperlink" id="goback">Go back</a>
```

Well, apparently the issue is with html  control. When I tried using button instead, it redirects fine. Any pointers yet to fix it, if in case I dont want button ?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET why not just use Response.Redirect? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I want to do it in jQuery. Using it at server-side is something I would prefer at the end as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried

```
document.location.pathname
```

I always use

```
window.location.href = 'mypageurlhere'
```

to redirect with javascript.

Comment: Since you can make it to this site, try doing `window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";` and if you still have problems there's something wrong with your browser. If that presents no problems, there's a problem elsewhere in your code and you will need to start providing some code samples of what's leading up to your redirection.

Comment: I updated my question. Looks like, the html control was issue. Please recheck once.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you're looking to redirect the user to a different page? If so, try this:

```
window.location.assign('page2.aspx');
```

Comment: Still takes me back to directory listing.

Comment: Are you sure the page exists? The redirection code works, so there may be another problem somewhere else.

Comment: I tried calling other pages as well. It doesnot work. I tried debugging, and can see the path. It doesnot change path to required one even after crossing the line where I redirect.